# Extract sequential and unique list of Years from Date Using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where I insert dates starting from cell A2. The column contains thousands of records with different years from 2009 (2009,2011,2014 etc.). In the same year I can also find hundreds of records and the list is really annoying to scroll record by record to get to the next year. I would like to extract, through VBA, the list of ALL individual years and populate a column, for example the K column, to have the sequential and unique list of the individual years of memorization of the records.

I already tried this code:

```
Public Sub test1()

  Dim rSrc As Range
  Dim rDst As Range

  Set rSrc = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
  Set rDst = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)

  rDst = rSrc
  rDst.NumberFormat = "yyyy"

End Sub
```

But it extract only one year from the entire column. I would like to get the list of all the years to be used in a listbox. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your requirment is not clear from the post. Do you want a list of years only. Why dont you sort the data. Share the sample data and required output data as picture. The code is only coying cell A1 from sheet1 to sheet2.

Comment: Dates formatted as `yyyy` are not necessarily unique. `04-Jul-2018` and `31-Dec-2018` will both display `2018` but are not unique.

Comment: I need to populate a listbox with the years to create charts depending on the year chosen. A simple copy and paste does not allow me to have a short list of all years. The code I used was an example found here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub test1()

    dim tmp as variant, yrs as object, i as long

    set yrs = createobject("scripting.dictionary")

    with worksheets("sheet1")

        'put all years into an array to save time looping through 'thousands of records'
        tmp = .range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup)).value2

        'transfer to dictionary keys as years for uniqueness
        for i = lbound(tmp, 1) to ubound(tmp, 1)
            yrs.item(year(tmp(i, 1))) = vbnullstring
        next i

        'put unique years back into column K
        .cells(2, "K").resize(yrs.count, 1) = application.transpose(yrs.keys)

        'sort unique years in column K
        with .range(.cells(2, "K"), .cells(.rows.count, "K").end(xlup))
            .sort key1:=.cells(1), order1:=xlascending, header:=xlno
        end with

    end with

end sub
```

Comment: Wow what a speed! Exactly the solution I was looking for. Thank you!